# how to add the half of the string to the old string?

Tags: c

suppose I have a 
char string[20];

And if I would like to read a string from a file using fscanf, and since the first char will always be skipped if I used fscanf(),

Then I will do the following like:

```
string[0] = x //where x is the char from fgetc();
```

then I will call fscanf, which will fill the remaining string[1- 19] for example, how do I archive this without using stringcat?

I tried something like

```
*string++;// but this give me a left operand error
```

for example:

input:

hello 123 1.2 '\n'
bye 124 0.02

code:

```
    while  ( ( y = fgetc( file2 ) ) != EOF )
    {
        if(y != '\n')
        {
            fscanf(file2,blah blah);//I scanf the string, the int and the double
        }
        else
        {
            printf(); // I will get everything on the line without the first char
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why will the first char be skipped?

Comment: fscanf only read the next char isn't it?

Comment: Not true. `man fscanf` and `man printf`. Or read K&R.

Comment: if I do  while  ( ( y = fgetc( file ) ) != EOF )
            { fscanf () } then it will read only starting from second char

Comment: But why would you do that?

Comment: because my file has lines of words I wanna read, and I need to detect where is the whitespace, so I can read correctly

Comment: Can you show some example input, and the results you expect?

Comment: You don't have to use `fgetc` to test for `EOF`. Look at the return value of `fscanf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to put the string read by the `fscanf()` starting from the element 1 of your array then you can use the following code:

```
fscanf(file2, "%18s", string+1);
```

`string` is an array object and not a pointer so you could not use the operation `string++` 
for an array object. because this is equivalent to :

```
string = string + 1;
```

Here you are assigning to the array object a new value which is not allowed in C.

What you can do to access to your string array from the element 1 is to use `string + 1` (without assigning it to the string array). `string + 1` return a pointer to  the element 1 of your `string` array